# Safari accesses Contacts

Tags: iphone, safari, security, contacts, privacy

I’m reading the App Privacy Report of my iPhone. It says that Safari accesses Contacts.

[image]

[image]

I‘ve never explicitly allowed it and  I don’t know why Safari does it.
I have disabled the use of contact information in Safari's autofill settings.

[image]

Why does Safari access Contacts? Is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not on by default, you'd have to allow it. It's not switched on in my phone. It would ask if you ever wanted to use auto-fill on a previously-visited site. I don't do a lot of web browsing on my phone, which is why it's never been requested. I do all that from my Mac, where I do have it switched on.

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of reasons this could be happening, but it likely comes down to Safari accessing your contacts database for something trivial. Apple should address this issues so that people don't run into what you're seeing, but:

One possibility is "Shared With You" which will show the name of the sender. This information could be embedded in the database, but it may just be the phone number that sent it - in which case Safari would have to lookup the name in Contacts to show "Shared by <Someone's name>"

Another example from another application is the App Store - which displays your profile picture in the top-right corner: This comes from your contacts, and the App Store will show up as accessing your contacts.

Comment: Isn't this access at least partially related to Safari autofilling your name/address/etc, in various web forms?

Comment: @SteveChambers They said they turned that off - and I'm working on the assumption that switch is taking proper effect